# Change ColorDrawable selected state color/ Tablayout background color programmatically

Tags: colors, tabs, background-color, android-tablayout, colordrawable

I've a tab_color_selector.xml drawable, I'm using it in TabLayout.

I want to change it's selected state color on onTabSelected.

tab_color_selector.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/medicine_green"
        android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/base_gray" />
</selector>
```

Tablayout xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/c_white"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/summary_blue"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5px"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/c_white"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/c_white" />
```

Here I want to change ColorDrawable android:state_selected="true" color programmatically.

```
  tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                                            ((ColorDrawable)tabLayout.getBackground()).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_yellow400));

                    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_17));
                    break;

                case 1:
                                            ((ColorDrawable)tabLayout.getBackground()).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_pink400));
                    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.out_pat_green));
                    break;


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

I tried both setColor() and setColorFilter() and also setBackground()

Answer (score 0):

Create a style and add it as a tag in your TabLayout widget

Comment: I want to change the selected tab background color on Run Time in tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener callback.